# how to remove all staff by using regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

Here's a copy of some of the lines (solution, pos and gloss) in my txt file:

```
solution: (كَتَبَ kataba) [katab-u_1] 
     pos: katab/VERB_PERFECT+a/PVSUFF_SUBJ:3MS
gloss: ___ + write + he/it <verb>
```

I would like to return the word 'katab' that inside the square brackets in first line and remove all staff and lines and number every things. I'm working on python 2.7

I tried to write this code:

```
pattern = re.compile("'(?P[^']+)':\s*(?P<root>[^,]*)\d+")
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, what you have tried so far and what's the problem with your code?

Comment: I tried to do this @  pattern = re.compile("'(?P[^']+)':\s*(?P<root>[^,]*)\d+")

Comment: @user5410951 We're asking you how exactly you tried that. There's a lot of people posting questions like yours and never trying to solve it themselves. If you show us what you've tried, and why you think it didn't work, we'll help you. Otherwise it's us writing your code for you.

Comment: If you want to no fall to such down votes you better to add your code to question and explain about it's problems!

Comment: I suggest to delete this question and ask another one with providing the code and explain about the problems

Comment: pcregrep -o1 --regexp="\[(.+)_.+\] $" ./input_file.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you think "I need to match a pattern", you should think "Regular Expressions" as a good starting point. See [doco](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). It is a little trickier since the input file is unicode.

```
import re
import codecs

with codecs.open("test.unicode.txt","rb", "utf-8") as f:
    words = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        matches = re.match(b"solution:.+\[(?P<word>\w+).*\]", line, flags=re.U)
        if matches:
            words.append(matches.groups()[0])

print(words)
```

Output:

```
[u'katab']
```